# Github pages - White look

Tags: github

Problem: When you click the link it shows only the title but nothing else

Why?

- This is the link to the repository: https://github.com/H4YWYRE/UHD-Food-Market
- and this is the link to the GitHub Pages: https://h4ywyre.github.io/UHD-Food-Market/

Current result:

[image: white look]

Comment: When you click the link it shows only the title but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

When I click https://github.com/H4YWYRE/UHD-Food-Market, I do see the full page, not just the title.

I would still recommand to rename [`FMPUHD.html`](https://github.com/H4YWYRE/UHD-Food-Market/blob/main/FMPUHD.html) as `index.html`, to kame sure this file is considered by default as the homepage.

Comment: It happened again when I made the changes, is this common? And if so how long until the updated version appears?

Comment: @SUB_ROSA Try and `git revert e67c76ff7cfbda13e90ec8ad179286ab668c760e`, then push and check if the issue persists.